# Creating Brew MP applications using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, brewmp

I have followed steps mentioned in https://brewmobileplatform.qualcomm.com/devnet/multiplatform_sdk.jsp#eclipse to install all the applications which includes Eclipse, Code Sourcery. If I create a application and try to run, a FlexNet dialog comes up asking for license file/server. How to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check Eclipse settings, there shall be CodeSourcery chosen in Brew MP settings, that will be used when you want to compile your program ang get mod/mod1 file. But if you want to test your program on simulator, you should choose Brew MP Simulation target (not physical target) in brew mp panel (actually, I haven't used Eclipse + Brew MP plugin but I guess it's the same as in MS VS).

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need Eclipse to develop BREW MP applications.  I use the make.d framework that comes with the SDK and you are free to use any editor you care for.

ed man!  man ed!